# Have MS Access press keys on keyboard

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have searched but this question is either too weird to phrase or there isn't any MS documentation.

I want access to press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, after a keyPress event on a form element. I have looked through the methods but I don't think it is there.

Comment: What do you want to achive with this shortcut?

Comment: I'm making a "search as you type" form with the results in a list box, and the control being a text box. But it doesn't work unless I change the focus out of the textbox, and back in. It changes the query at run time after each key press. If I fixed this, it would be the best way I know for this type of functionality.

Comment: Then use mwolfe02's solution with `SetFocus`. I implemented a "search as you type" once, but without changing focus etc. How does your function look?

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    SendKeys "{TAB}"
    SendKeys "+{TAB}"
End Sub
```

However, this is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something like Google's Instant Search, then you should use the textbox's OnChange event, and run the search each time that event is called.

I wouldn't recommend that, though. You might want to skip the search until the search text is 3 characters or longer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SendKeys** to do this.

However, that should be a last resort.  Depending on what you are trying to achieve the `.SetFocus` method on individual controls will work more reliably.